# changing label color 2 times within a funtion in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-label

I have a funtion, that parses the log. I am updating the label color and text at  different lines within the same funtion. I see that only the last changed color and text only reflecting in the UI. i do not see the intermediate color and text changes.

Below is my code:

```
def OnclickLogParser(self):
    if LogFileName == '':
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Please select a valid Log")
    if LogPathName == '':
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Please select a valid Log Path")
    self.lb_log_status.configure(bg="#08DFE8", fg="#010101", text='Parsing inProgress...')
    m_logParser = CAdpBrrLogParser()
    m_logReader = CAdpBrrLogReader('mrr', m_logParser)
    status = m_logReader.readFile(LogPathName)
    if status == True:
        self.lb_log_status.configure(bg="#F6F50B", fg="#010101", text='Log Ready')
        self.btn_log_start["state"] = "normal"
    global m_injector
    m_injector = CAdpUdpDataInjector()
```

you can see that i am changing the color and text of `lb_log_status` at two different places. The time gap between those two lines would be around 3 -5 secs. But i can not witness the first color change. '

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter must process events regularly to perform any UI operations. If you want to see the color changes here you have to give Tk a chance to process the configuration and paint events that get generated when you re-configure a widget. Your code just immediately starts processing the log and will not process any events until this function exits and you return to the Tk `mainloop()` which is the event processing method. You would see the same problem if you used a progress bar widget and tried to update the progress during processing.

One way to resolve this is to use the Tk `after()` method and schedule your processing in chunks that take a limited amount of time per chunk. After reading and processing a chunk call `after()` again to schedule the next chunk.

Another method is to put the processing on a worker thread and use `event_generate()` to post events back to the Tk thread to announce progress and completion.